# Applet needs to read an XML located outside the JAR

Tags: java, jar, applet

I know there already have been quite a few questions regarding this topic but I couldn't find one for my problem.

I'm simply creating a JAVA applet that reads  from an xml file and then does what it has to do with it. When I test in in Eclipse, it works fine with the following code (week1 being a button!):

```
week1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                parseXMLFile("../../week1.xml", teams);
                updateTable(teams);
          }
        });
```

As the .java file is in the src folder and the xml is at the root, this "../../week1.xml" does the trick. But when I export the applet as a JAR and insert it in an HTML page, the page loads with the applet but when I click the week1 button, nothing happens (I'm almost certain that it's because it does not find the xml file as it's outside the JAR archive). 
I get this error in the Java console:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.dir" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at java.io.Win32FileSystem.getUserPath(Unknown Source)
at java.io.Win32FileSystem.resolve(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.getAbsolutePath(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.getAbsoluteFile(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.toURI(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at skullBall.parseXMLFile(skullBall.java:77)
at skullBall.access$0(skullBall.java:70)
at skullBall$1.actionPerformed(skullBall.java:52)
```

I would like to have the .jar archive and the xml file at the same location, how can I do this as the code inside the JAR needs to read the xml that's outside?

Thanks a lot

Comment: *"when I click the week1 button, nothing happens"*  It almost certainly does.  Check the Java Console for output.  Debugging applets without the console open is like trying to fight with one arm tied behind your back.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I do this as the code inside the JAR needs to read the xml that's outside?

1. Put the XML in a path on the server where you can access it using your browser (check by trying to show it in a browser, via. the server/localhost).
2. Access the resource by URL.  To form that URL, use a path relative to the [document base](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase%28%29) or [code base](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29) of the applet.

#### E.G.

```
URL urlToXml = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "the.xml");
```

---

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (
    "java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.dir" "read")
```

That should be solved by accessing the XML via URL relative to the document (or code) base.

Comment: That sounds good...I'll try and do something with that and I'll get back to you! And I did have a look at the console, the error is at the line where the parseXMLFile() function is called! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing for me.
As I understand it the `XML` file is yours and it is expected to be always in the same location (i.e. the end-user is not expected to provide a different `XML` for example).
So why don't you deliver the file **inside the jar** so that you can use a relative path? Why are you trying to read it from outside the jar?

Comment: The XML file **will** change. The end-user (me) will replace the old xml file with another one that has different content but the same name. I just don't want to repack the jar file every time I need to change the content of the XML